# c# | How can i create dynamic controller from plugin assembly

Tags: c#, mef

Since the application I want to do is large, I want to divide it into parts and therefore I want to use the plugin structure. The structure I want to build will hold controllers in plugins and will be added as a route to the main structure. I can do this with "AddApplicationPart" but the route system is not working as I want. So, what I want to do is to find the controls from my plugin and create dynamic controllers like "new controller" or somehow set a dynamic route to the controls I created.

Thank you...

Comment: You can do it with ApplicationParts but you need each controller to have RouteAttribute and that will be picked up.  Other alternative is to use some Reflection but only if you are comfortable with reflection.

Comment: @AliK First of all, thank you for your attention. I tried make with RouteAttribute and made one parent class and inherited it with sealed class, but the last route attribute is used, it is not chained.

[route("base/")]
AController

[route("second")] // Cant access with 'base/second' only access 'second'
BController: AController

Comment: I have this working so I am wondering what your startup.cs looks like.

Comment: You could try with source generators, take a look at this https://github.com/amis92/csharp-source-generators

Comment: [startup.cs](https://www.codepile.net/pile/mGoxPrM2)

Comment: @JesusSantander I have examined it, but since there are different solutions, I could not fully grasp the logic.